# How to remove /blog from url in Joomla

Tags: joomla

I created a Category Blog on my Joomla site but there's a problem. Joomla is adding /blog automatically to urls and as a result, images aren't displayed since blog/images/ doesn't exist. Is there a way to either remove blog/ from urls or correct image links to display /images instead of /blog/images? These are the links:

http://www.gambitchessacademy.com/blog

http://www.gambitchessacademy.com/blog/10-using-time-efficiently-during-a-tournament-game

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Fist, your real problem is about **Relative** VS **Absolute URLs**. See http://kb.iu.edu/data/abwp.html for example.

For example a javascript file on **js/jquery.js** is a relative URL. If you are on **site.com/blog/article.html** it will try http://example.com/blog/js/jquery.js. But if you use **/js/jquery.js** or http://example.com/js/jquery.js you will have your real problem solved.

Note the "/" at start of paths. They make a lot of diference.